# JSON Error - object cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, json

I am having this code :

```
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    in method -
    JSONArray reportList = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray repAuthList = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject repAuthObj = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject calendarCountObj = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject reportObj = new JSONObject();

    calendarCountObj.put("May-2011", "3");
    calendarCountObj.put("June-2011", "2");
    calendarCountObj.put("Oct-2011", "5");
    calendarCountObj.put("Dec-2011", "8");
    repAuthObj.put("calCountMap", calendarCountObj);
    repAuthObj.put("RAname", "RA1");
    repAuthList.put(reportingAuthorityObj);
    reportObj.put("RAList", reportingAuthorityObj);
    reportObj.put("deptName", "Ennovate");
    reportList.put(reportObj);
```

But when I debug this code, I get this error - `calendarCountObj cannot be resolved to a variable`

I have already declared/define them above stil I am getting this.
This error is for all the variables.
Please help..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you added the corresponding JAR to the classpath?

Comment: Yes. It seems working in another class in same package.

Comment: OK, what do you mean by "when I debug this code"? Is it a runtime error message? How do you get it?

Comment: When I inspect that variable using ctrl+shift+I in eclipse, I don't get its value but I get above error.I don't get any RuntimeException.Also control flows smoothly without any error.

Comment: I just refreshed my project folder and restarted eclipse and it worked.! However thanks a lot for your time n help. @all

Comment: Uh-oh... Good luck with your project! :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the missing JSON-lib jar file as part of the WEB-INF directory. Include this jar file and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I got resolved this issue. See my comments above.